# my client’s site is confused between Wordpress.com and Wordpress.org I think

Tags: installation

I created a site for a client years back using Wordpress. When I was hired, the site already had a theme and Wordpress installed successfully. I made edits and added content and that was that. The site was and has always been hosted on GoDaddy. I did not look into how Wordpress was installed. All I knew at the time was that I could log into /wp-admin. My client just added something, however that has caused an issue. The site is right here
http://dorothypaynepolk.com/

My client tried to add a blog with a theme that differs from the one on her existing site.  Now the only page that sill load is  http://dorothypaynepolk.com/blog

Any ideas what’s going on? I need to somehow delete whatever blog plugin and has...

Comment: I can't see anything obvious sorry. Any chance you have backups from before the change so you can compare before and after? Otherwise I'd probably start by looking at the server error logs to work out what's wrong with /wp-admin, or moving all the plugin files to disable them and see if that helps.

Comment: I wondered if /blog was a separate WordPress install, but at first glance I don't think so - I guess it could be a subdomain multisite? Any chance your client can tell you what they did?

Comment: both pages are loading for me